# executing javascript popup in html <a> tag that are echo-ed in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

the flow is: a php page calls an ajax function that displays a list of user in a table without refreshing the pages. in this table, i put a delete and edit link. I have no problem with the delete link however, i'm stuck at the edit link.

what I'm trying to do is, when a user click edit link, there will appear a popup window, there, they can update the details of the user, but it appears that my popup window is not appearing.

the javascript function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newWindow(url) { 
var x,y;
x = screen.width-35;
y = screen.height-30;
var win =       window.open(url,'glossaryWindow','toolbar=no,directories=no,width=500,height=500'+
        'screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0,location=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resize=yes,menubar=no');
    }
```

i put the function at the top of the page.

this is the php code to call java function in  html tag

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="javascript: newWindow("/test/HTMLPages/popup_update_user.html")">edit</a>' . "</td>";
```

is it possible??

i checked it its my URL that wrong, but that is not the problem. the popup does not appear at all. i need advise on this matter.

UPDATE:

this is the correct code for calling javascript in  tag within php:

```
 <?php
    echo "<td>" . "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"newWindow('popup_update_user.html')\">edit</a>". "</td>"; ?>
```

:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the echo you are opening and closing the statement before calling the javascript function.

And don't call the function in the "href", call it from "onclick".

Try this:

```
echo "<td> <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"newWindow('/test/HTMLPages/popup_update_user.html')\">edit</a></td>";
```

**EDIT:**
Working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function newWindow(url) { 
            var x,y;
            x = screen.width-35;
            y = screen.height-30;
            var win =       window.open(url,'glossaryWindow','toolbar=no,directories=no,width=500,height=500'+
                    'screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0,location=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resize=yes,menubar=no');
                }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <?php
                echo "<td> <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"newWindow('/test/HTMLPages/popup_update_user.html')\">edit</a></td>";
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. but when i tried, it did not work. the page says object not found'

Comment: meaning?? sorry for the non-stop questions.. i'm new to this.

Comment: it opens a new window right ? but in that window it says "object not found" right ? If that's the case then the url : "/test/HTMLPages/popup_update_user.html" is wrong

Comment: It depends the browser you are using, but if you are using any recent browser it should work, but for the sanity check try this.
var win = window.open(url,'glossaryWindow_'+Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),'toolbar=no,directories=no,width=500,height=500'+
                    'screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0,location=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resize=yes,menubar=no');

Comment: Replace your var win with that

Comment: thank you !! i have to turn it around a little but it works!! :D. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: If so please select my answer as the correct one :)